# Nested count on a condition in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL. I am developing a chat application to get chat conversations like in Facebook. I have written the following query:

```
select m.toid, m.fmid, m.message, m.seen
from messages m
where ((toid = 5 or fmid = 5))
  and not exists (select 1 from messages m2
                  where greatest (m2.toid, m2.fmid) = reatest(m.toid,m.fmid)
                    and least (m2.toid, m2.fmid) = least(m.toid,m.fmid)
                    and m2.message_id > m.message_id )
order by message_id desc
```

Above query returns as shown below.

[image: MySql WorkBench]

Explanation from picture: the last message between 5 and 4 is fghhgj and the message is not seen. Now I want to get number of messages which are not seen between 5 and 4.

I mean I want to get count of seen where `seen=0`.

In Brief:

Message table contains column called seen. If message is not seen, its value is 0. Now I want to get how many messages are not seen for every conversation.

Comment: add `having seen=0` to your query

Comment: @Jens then I will get records  which have `seen=0` only. I have to get all conversations with count of `seen=0`

Comment: Sorry it is not really clear for me what you need.

Comment: Yes.Post the expected output. that will help us to understand ur problem better

Comment: Perhaps your question is unclear

Comment: @Jens I have to get count of seen column where `seen=0` for every conversation that I am retrieving from query that I specified in question.

Comment: @Strawberry Now I have added some description.

Comment: Well, it's still a very poor explanation.

Answer (score 4):

To count the # of rows where `seen` is equal to 0 in your result set, put your query inside of a derived table and use `select count(*)` with `where seen = 0`

```
select count(*) from (
    select m.toid,m.fmid,m.message,m.seen from messages m 
    where (toid = 5 or fmid = 5) 
    and not exists (select 1 from messages m2 where 
    greatest(m2.toid,m2.fmid) = greatest(m.toid,m.fmid) and
    least(m2.toid,m2.fmid) = least(m.toid,m.fmid) and m2.message_id > m.message_id )
) t1 where seen = 0
```

**Edit**

Your updated explanation seems to indicate you want the # of unseen messages for every conversation. If so, select all messages where `seen` equals 0 and group them by participants using `greatest` and `least`.

```
select least(toid,fmid), greatest(toid,fmid), count(*)
from messages
where seen = 0
group by least(toid,fmid), greatest(toid,fmid)
```

If you also need to include conversations with no unseen messages (i.e. count=0), then remove the `where seen = 0` condition and replace `count(*)` with `sum(seen=0)`, where `seen=0` evaluates to either a 1 or 0.

```
select least(toid,fmid), greatest(toid,fmid), sum(seen=0)
from messages
group by least(toid,fmid), greatest(toid,fmid)
```

To select additional columns, join `messages` to a derived table containing the counts:

```
select m.*, t1.seen_count from messages m
join (
    select least(toid,fmid) leastid, greatest(toid,fmid) greatestid, sum(seen=0) seen_count
    from messages
    group by least(toid,fmid), greatest(toid,fmid)
) t1 on t1.leastid = least(m.toid,fmid) and t1.greatestid = greatest(m.toid,fmid)
```

Comment: I got it. But I have to get all columns that returning from query that I provided in my question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the count where the `seen = 0` use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM messages WHERE seen = 0;
```

**OR**

within your query only just add `COUNT(*) AS TOTAL` before specifying the table's name within your query and `WHERE seen = 0` in the `where` clause.
It'll return all the records with `seen = 0` but with an extra column `TOTAL`.
Hope you wanted this. If you need anything else please explain.